# why is thepiratebay.se listed as deceptive site in Chrome and other browsers

Tags: web-browser, websites

Why is thepiratebay.se listed as deceptive site in Chrome and other browsers? My Norton says nothing about fishing or malware.

There is no doubt that some organisations doesn't like thepiratebay but is there real security threat or just politically motivated site block?

I don't ask this to discus piracy I am more concerned for possible false alarm if thepiratebay is enlisted as security threat without exact security reason.

With such praxis we can't rely on security alerts in browsers anymore because we will become unsure is it real security threat or result of campaign of some organisations with enough money to put someone on security block list.

[image]

edit:

I agree with you totally @baconface sir. Can you say everything you said for this site also:
http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/6617311/rizzoli-isles-hide-and-seek-nl ? This is well known subtitle download site. It isn't enlisted as threat. Yet of course, but we shall see... all those argumentation works only on one site.

Internet is full of such examples and simply, user have to be careful, Internet isn't environment adapted to least intelligent person in the network.

Respecting all yours, no doubt, valid argumentation, google should enlisted as threat much more sites which is not in case, so threshold or trigger to be enlisted as threat apparently is something else.

Comment: A large portion of the pirated software, or it's associated cracks, is infected with malicious software. Pirate at your own risk.

Comment: @MarkBuffalo but content of site are not cracks or malware

Comment: Actually, have you visited the download pages without uBlock? They're *riddled* with fake download links to try and get you to download malicious software. The site in general is pretty unsafe without NoScript/uBlock... and that's before you get to the potentially-infected downloads hosted by others, and then you have the users who think scanning it for viruses proves that it's safe or not.

Comment: I must admit I didn't

Comment: [Google has started blocking websites that show fake download buttons](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122558/why-is-thepiratebay-se-listed-as-deceptive-site-in-chrome-and-other-browsers?atw=1).

Answer (score 1):

“Attackers on thepiratebay.se may trick you into doing something dangerous like installing software or revealing your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, or credit cards).” well that should answer your question. 
These types of warnings typically occur when an ad network is compromised and starts serving malicious ads. Because sites often use multiple advertising networks, some specific to certain regions, not all users are always affected. In short, at least one of The Pirate Bay’s pages is serving up malware, according to Google.

Comment: Using AdBlock and NoScript would significantly reduce the risks associated with visiting pages of a questionable nature, of course, since malicious ads usually require scripting and being rendered in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should trust the warning.

Some sites tend to have generally weaker security and/or use ad networks that are shady. When a vulnerability is found by Google, they block the site. The site owners generally respond to this problem by correcting the security problem. They'll then notify Google (or Google will notice on its own), and, assuming the problem is fixed, Chrome will stop blocking the site.

So don't visit the site until Google says it's safe. If you must visit it, using browser extensions such as AdBlock and NoScript will make it much safer. (Thanks to @phyrfox for the AdBlock/NoScript idea.)

*Update:* [multiple browsers](https://yro.slashdot.org/story/16/05/08/0030230/the-pirate-bay-now-blocked-in-chrome-firefox-and-safari?utm_source=rss1.0mainlinkanon&utm_medium=feed) were blocking the site. The assumption is that the problem was malvertising (malware from ads). At least for me, the site is now accessible in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is related to the ads. The Pirate Bay has not only been using deceptive ads but it appears they allow their usage as this is a very well known ongoing practice by them.

As you can see below you have a typical torrent page on PB. Which is the correct download link? If you guessed the big download button you guessed wrong. That is malware or adware served through an ad of a third party. Sometimes these pages have several download buttons all over the page with even more convincing details. But the tiny "GET THIS TORRENT" link is the only legitimate torrent link. Even the stream it, anonymous download, and upgrade links could link you to adware/malware.

[image: Pirate Bay ad malware]